Is it best to let sleeping dogs lie? A.k.a. What to do about answers that are verifiably false?
(I did search before posting. Mostly all I found was AI-related, or beloved-moderator-that-was-summarily-de-modded-related, or even the Misleading information policy-related.)
What should be done about answers that are verifiably wrong? Not suspected wrong, not disagreed on, not a matter of opinion wrong, but just absolutely wrong? The answer doesn't threaten democracy, or significantly contribute to the risk of physical or psychological harm, etc. It's not even remotely newsworthy. It's merely annoying. Seriously. (Like the Oxford comma, which I happen to like a lot. Damned if you do, and damned if you don't use it in a lot of cases.)
Clearly a comment suggesting an improvement is warranted. Comments are easily ignored.
Clearly a flag is wrong. Moderators are not tasked with evaluating the veracity of answers, thank (the higher powers)!
Is anything else warranted? I'm asking because I'm a bit torn. (Well, more since I'm posting here.)
We are supposed to be a repository of expert answers (well, that's what the founders hoped for anyway.) What does it matter if an answer is a fabrication?
Maybe that's the answer: What does it matter if an answer is a fabrication?
Hence, should I let the answer lie?
Mind you, a fabrication implies that the user posting such an answer is fully aware of the nature of their answer.
Edited to add: I commented. I provided support for my comment. user changed the embarrassingly wrong photograph they had used as "proof" and substituted a equally wrong but different photo of a fabricated scenario as "proof" and then misinterpreted (?) a quote, and went on to opine - to mind read - how a fictional person might "possibly" have made a mistake (that was not a mistake) supporting why their wrong answer is right. Everything, and I mean everything is wrong in the answer. I've never seen an answer exactly as wrong in every respect as this one on the network before tonight. At the OP's request, I answered as well. The OP then accepted the other answer. Oh, well. I'm done.

Commenting would be an option, if you're willing to

the idea being someone looking at the answer will read the comments too. Its the best you can do sometimes

@JourneymanGeek - Agreed, and thanks. Sincerely. It's not important at this point. I tried to delete my question, but could not as i has an answer.

@JourneymanGeek but comments can be deleted at any time.

If an answer is wrong, downvote it. It's as simple as that.
If there's another correct answer then upvote that. If not, then answer the question yourself and make it clear why it's the right answer i.e. show your evidence/reasoning.
Subject matter experts might delete a wrong answer if they have the privilige to do so but that doesn't often happen because there are so few of them.

I am the "subject matter expert". Possibly the only subject matter expert aware of this particular wrong answer. I can't delete it, but thanks anyway.

"Subject matter experts might delete a wrong answer if they have the privilige to do" very often they cannot. Because the wrong answer has a positive score and deletion requires it to be negative. A wrong answer with +5 or even +10 might just be effectively untouchable. And there are wrong answers out there at +15 or even +50. Only then does what you said come into effect - it's hard to even get enough eyes on wrong answers. Enough eyes that also have deletion privilege. But that is not really the first hurdle.

@VLAZ that's mostly true only on Stack Overflow (and maybe a tiny number of other sites). On the site I moderate there's very little voting at all so if a non-moderator did manage to become a trusted user they could pretty much cast a delete vote on anything they wanted. Of course they would never find another two trusted users so it's that that would prevent their delete votes from being useful.
